# Create ErrorDocument scripts that automatically report broken URLs

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, errordocument

Is there an easy way to do this, in f.ex. .htaccess?

I've tried passing the request or request uri as parameter to a PHP file, but of course the ErrorDocument command is not a RewriteRule.

Ideally I'd just log it or send an email with the offending URL and tell the visitor that the webmaster has been notified. Email would be best since I'd be able to get notified immediately.

Comment: Can you put content of your `.htaccess` here?

Comment: Well, the only relevant portion is `ErrorDocument 404 index.php`, I'm sort of midstage building the site. So the problem isn't that I can't call a script, it's that once I'm on `index.php` I don't what URL it was, that wasn't found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it is possible.
All you have to do is to put this line in your htaccess (for example, with 404 error)

```
ErrorDocument 404 /log.php
```

You can change the path to match its real location.

Then, in your php file, you can get the url with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

Example: `http://www.domain.com/unknown/url/does/not/exist`
In this case: `REQUEST_URI` = `/unknown/url/does/not/exist`

Comment: ***Hm*** I'm ashamed! I just tested now and it works. I was sure that `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` would give me /log.php in your case. I should have just tried it. Seems to be the original URL as well, before rewrites. Thanks a lot, anyway. I'll be putting this to good use!